# I am getting a following error while using pycharm in windows 8.1

Tags: django, python-3.x, pycharm

I have started working on python/django. But while using settings.py for database connection, I am getting the following error. I am using pycharm in windows 8.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.0.6\bin\runnerw.exe" C:\Python34\python.exe "C:/Users/hp user/PycharmProjects/edu/manage.py" runserver 8000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 24, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/hp user/PycharmProjects/edu/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 41, in <module>
    class Permission(models.Model):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 139, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 324, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 250, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 36, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 240, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 27, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author used windows 8 and Python 3.4. mysql-python is not compatible with Python 3.x. Please use mysqlclient

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Comment: I found the solution. We need PyMySQL with mysqlclient

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the missing module with:

```
pip install mysql-python
```

(you might require sudo).